# Why PHP isn't use the variable declared outside of POST?

Tags: php

I need some help about how to pass a variable with POST without using sessions.

Currently my code doesn't display value of the variable called $myvariable:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['testbutton'])){
if ($_POST['testbutton'] == 'Testing') {

echo $myvariable;
var_dump($_POST);

}
}

$myvariable = "hello world";

echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Testing" name="testbutton"/>';
echo '</form>';

?>
```

What should I change in the code to be able to use $variable in POST['testbutton'] part of the code ?

Comment: you're trying to call `$myvariable` before you define it.  Move 
`$myvariable = "hello world";` to the top

Comment: Define it _before_ you try to use it

Comment: Move `$myvariable = "hello world";` at top

Comment: PHP statements are executed in order. Why would you think you can use the result of an assignment before the assignment?

Comment: If you want to pass a variable using POST, add a hidden input to the form and get its value inside the `if` statement.

Comment: And no need to use it `if ($_POST['testbutton'] == 'Testing') {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment:

```
<?php

$myvariable = "hello world";

if(isset($_POST['testbutton'])){
    if ($_POST['testbutton'] == 'Testing') {

        echo $myvariable;
        var_dump($_POST);

    }
}



echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Testing" name="testbutton"/>';
echo '</form>';

?>
```

**UPDATE**

If what you're trying to do is pass a variable from the page to `$_POST` you'll need to do as jeroen suggested and set a hidden input like this:

```
  echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $myvariable .'" name="myvariable"/>';
```

this will then become `$_POST["myvariable"]`

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants, but it's not exactly clear from the question...

Comment: I think no need to use this `if ($_POST['testbutton'] == 'Testing') {`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

// define $mvvariable here and PHP will not bring undefined error
$myvariable = "hello world";

if(isset($_POST['testbutton'])){
if ($_POST['testbutton'] == 'Testing') {

echo $myvariable;
var_dump($_POST);

}
}


echo '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Testing" name="testbutton"/>';
echo '</form>';

?>
```